# Finding the original number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Q. When a two digit number is subtracted from the same number with its
>   digits reversed, the result is one less than the original number. If
>   three times the tens digit (of the original number) is added to four
>   times the units digit (of the original number), the result is the
>   number itself. Find the original number.

Here are some observations I made:

1. the ones place cannot be greater than the 10's

Example: $13$, because $13-31$ will result in a negative number.

2. the number in the ones place cannot equal the number on the tens place.

Example: $22$ because $22-22=0$ and we need $1$ less which would be $21$ in this case.

The only number that I found was $10$ but $3(1)+4(0)=3$ and does not equal $10$.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are looking for integers $n_{1}, n_{2}$ between $0$ and $9$ such that:

$10n_{2} + n_{1} - (10n_{1} + n_{2}) = 10n_{1} + n_{2} - 1$

and

$3n_{1} + 4n_{2} = 10n_{1} + n_{2}$.

The first equation reduces to $19n_{1} - 8n_{2} = 1$ and the second equation reduces to $7n_{1} - 3n_{2} = 0$.

You can now solve this system of equations $\begin{cases} 19n_{1} - 8n_{2} = 1 \\  7n_{1} - 3n_{2} = 0 \end{cases} $ to get your answer.

Comment: I get $n_1=\frac{3}{73}$ and $n_2=\frac{7}{73}$ but didnt you say the $n_1$ and $n_2$ need to be integers

Comment: @CaddyHeron Originally, yes, because we had a two digit number to start with.  Based on your solution, the original answer should now be $10(\frac{3}{73}) + \frac{7}{73} = \frac{30 + 7}{73}$, and this isn't a two digit number.  So, either your solution is incorrect, or the way I went about the problem is incorrect, though I'm not sure where I would be wrong at.

Comment: my professor said there was an error in one of the questions he assigned but didn't mention which one. It could be possible that there is a detail forgotten about this problem.

Comment: @CaddyHeron Maybe, but it's also very possible my solution is flawed.  I am getting a feeling that my solution might be flawed, so I will keep thinking about it.  Maybe someone else will respond before I figure it out.

Comment: I shall look it over.

Comment: If the original two digit number is $10n_1 + n_2$, then the number with its digits reversed is $10n_2 + n_1$.  Therefore, the condition that when a two-digit number is subtracted from the same number with its digits reversed, the result is one less than the original number means $\color{red}{10n_2 + n_1 - (10n_1 + n_2)} = 10n_1 + n_2 - 1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You're right!  Let's see if that fixes the answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig That fixed it!  The solutions are now $n_{1} = 3$ and $n_{2} = 7$, so the original number is $37$.

Answer (score 0):

Given 19n1 - 8n2 = 1  7n1 - 3n2 = 0
 7n1 = 3n2
7(19n1 - 8n2) = 7
133n1 - 56n2  = 7
57n2 - 56n2   = 7    n2 = 7  n1 = 3 original number =37

Comment: Please use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and make sure your answer is constructive, and gives a step-by-step solution to help the author the most. Formatting matters - otherwise who is going to bother to read your post?